# How to integrate Linphone into IOS Swift - Developing iOS 7 / 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, linphone

I'm new to iOS Development but I know C#, Python and Java. I'm looking to integrate Linphone into IOS project via Swift programming language.

I found a build of Linphone with all security features enabled at: 
https://github.com/guardianproject/linphone-ios-secure

I build and ran the hello-world with no errors but nothing came up in the simulator.

What is the best way to start my project,  I’ve created my storyboard to pass by configuration for my SIP account. I include all Lib’s and h files in my build setting and it compile with no errors.

My goal is to programmatically place a video call using Linphone.

Does anyone have a sample Swift or Objective-C  XCode 6 project or  code snippet?

Thanks in advance!!!!!
Stan

Comment: Better you go through README file of linphone project and follow all steps. Also, you can refer this [link](http://shallwelearn.com/blog/build-linphone-for-iphone-and-ipad/). :-)